# How can I remove the space around radio buttons in IE 6?

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer-6

IE 6 seems to add some non-margin space around radio buttons. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per the SitePoint forums](http://web.archive.org/web/20110531013241/http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/css-53/removing-padding-around-[input-type=checkbox]-438185.html), if you give the radio button a specific height/width, this will get rid of the extra space.

Comment: Why did you ask a question and answer it yourself 1 minute later?

Comment: @recursive: because I’d found the solution before I’d asked the question, but I wanted to a) remember it; b) see if anyone had any better suggestions or knew of any problems with this solution; and c) bring the information out of a closed forum post and into Stack Overflow, where people can edit and vote on it. To quote the fourth paragraph of [the Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): “It’s... perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question”.

Comment: @recursive: I probably should have made it a Community Wiki question though. (Then again, that doesn’t seem to be an option any more?)

Comment: Further info on answering your own question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/