# How can I remove the space before a checkbox in IE 6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I know this is an age old question with almost a gazillion answers but none of them seem to apply to IE 6. I also tried the method suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344551/how-can-i-remove-the-space-around-radio-buttons-in-ie-6) without much luck.

The only solution that comes close to working is creating a `div` with `border` and then explicitly mentioning the `height` and `width` and then specifying `margin:0`. But this reduces the size of the checkbox greatly.

Is there a neat way to do it, with as little overhead as possible?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `padding-left`, `text-indent`, and `margin-left` to 0 / 0px?

Comment: @xDaevax No luck. Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried all `*-left` CSS Properties.

Answer (score 0):

S4san,

try this. You have to write CSS Hack for IE 6.

```
<style type="text/css">
    *{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Tahoma; color:#333; font-size:12px;}
    .chk_bx{margin:-4px -3px 0 -4px !ie; vertical-align:top;}
</style>

<input type="checkbox" class="chk_bx" />Your Text
```

Comment: Is there a neater method? This looks like a very laborious workaround for a small problem.

Comment: I hope so. B'coz, there is no one give solution to hide the spaces between checkbox till now.. Right??? Then, Why don't you try this until the next solution.